# can not remove dom breakpoint in the Chrome devtool for mac

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image]

I can not remove this dom breakpoint in the Chrome devtool for mac, Please help me! Thanks a lot.  Everytime I refresh the page, the dom breakpoint come out. I even tried reinstall chrome just now.

chrome version: Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
mac version: High sierra

I wonder are there some physical caches about these breakpoints config exist? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you right click on the breakpoint?

Comment: @BennettHardwick The `Remove breakpoint & Remove all the breakpoints` not work. The breakpoint show again when I refresh the page.

Comment: Can we assume you closed and restarted the browser? Check whether there are no more chrome processes using `ps` after stopping Chrome. Did you try to remove the breakpoint via the context menu on the `body` node in the "Elements" panel?

Comment: @try-catch-finally Thanks. I tried to remove the breakpoint via the context menu on tht body node in the Elements" panel too. I checked that there is no chrome processe after I quit Chrome. I reopen chrome, and the breakpoint come back again.~~

Comment: Help! I am almost desperate. The breakpoint works when I refresh the page everytime.